# Create an assoc array with equal keys and values from a regular array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like

```
$numbers = array('first', 'second', 'third');
```

I want to have a function that will take this array as input and return an array that would look like:

```
array(
'first' => 'first',
'second' => 'second',
'third' => 'third'
)
```

I wonder if it is possible to use `array_walk_recursive` or something similar...

Comment: wow, thanks for your answers so quickly. the first two answers will work, but I was just looking for something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You can use the [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function, like so:

```
$numbers = array('first', 'second', 'third');
$result = array_combine($numbers, $numbers);
```

Comment: This is great for one-liners.  Here is a use case for expiration month:$months = array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 10), range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 10)).

Answer (score 4):

This simple approach should work:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($numbers as $n){
  $new_array[$n] = $n;
}
```

You can also do something like:

`array_combine(array_values($numbers), array_values($numbers))`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
function toAssoc($array) {
    $new_array = array();
    foreach($array as $value) {
        $new_array[$value] = $value;
    }       
    return $new_array;
}
```